# Obtain hexadecimal color codes used in “scale_fill_grey” function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to get the hexadecimal codes of the colors that the `scale_fill_grey` function uses to fill the categories of the barplot produced by the following codes:

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
  Meal = factor(c("Breakfast","Lunch","Dinner","Snacks"), 
  levels=c("Breakfast","Lunch","Dinner","Snacks")),
  Cost = c(9.75,13,19,10.20))

ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Meal, y=Cost, fill=Meal)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")  +
    scale_fill_grey(start=0.8, end=0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: First row in `?scale_fill_grey`: "Based on `gray.colors`"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`scale_fill_grey()` uses `grey_pal()` from the `scales` package, which in turn uses `grey.colors()`. So, you can generate the codes for the scale of four colours that you used as follows:

```
grey.colors(4, start = 0.8, end = 0.2)
## [1] "#CCCCCC" "#ABABAB" "#818181" "#333333"
```

This shows a plot with the colours

```
image(1:4, 1, matrix(1:4), col = grey.colors(4, start = 0.8, end = 0.2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `ggplot_build()` function:

```
#assign ggplot to a variable
myplot <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Meal, y=Cost, fill=Meal)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")  +
  scale_fill_grey(start=0.8, end=0.2)

#get build
myplotBuild <- ggplot_build(myplot)

#see colours
myplotBuild$data

# [[1]]
#      fill x     y PANEL group ymin  ymax xmin xmax colour size linetype alpha
# 1 #CCCCCC 1  9.75     1     1    0  9.75 0.55 1.45     NA  0.5        1    NA
# 2 #ABABAB 2 13.00     1     2    0 13.00 1.55 2.45     NA  0.5        1    NA
# 3 #818181 3 19.00     1     3    0 19.00 2.55 3.45     NA  0.5        1    NA
# 4 #333333 4 10.20     1     4    0 10.20 3.55 4.45     NA  0.5        1    NA
```